# html element got focused by mouse or keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How can I find out a HTML-Element (lets say a `select`-tag) got focus by mouse-click, keyboard or JavaScript function?

```
<select onfocus="foo(event)"></select>

<script>
function foo(e) {
    if (e.??? == 'mouse') {
        //do something
    }
    else if (e.??? == 'keyboard') {
        //do something different
    }
}
</script>
```

I also tried to add an `onclick` event to the element but the `onfocus` event fires first.

Comment: Please try the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148359/determine-focus-event-click-or-tabstop

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any native way to see how the element received its focus (correct my if I'm wrong!).

However, you may be able to do something like store when the mouse is clicked, store when the keyboard is used and then react based on the last active state.

```
var inputState = null;

document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKey);

function handleClick () {
    inputState = "mouse";
}

function handleKey () {
    inputState = "keyboard";
}

function foo() {
    if ( inputState === "mouse" ) {
         // mouse code   
    } else if ( inputState === "keyboard" ) {
         // keyboard code   
    } else {
         // Function was called directly   
    }

    // Reset input State after processing
    inputState = null
}
```

This will likely need some adjustments but I hope you can use this to find the correct answer.

Edit:

My answer is a vanilla JS solution, if you have access to jQuery you may want to investigate the `click` and `keyup` event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.activeElement, it is supported in all major browsers. It can give you the current active element.

**EDIT**

Oops I think I misunderstood your question. you want to identify the mouse or keyboard or programmatic

For programmatic
if(e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) {
    // Focus event was manually triggered.
}

To differentiate between keyboard and mouse based focus events
You have to hack it by adding an extra keydown event and understand. You can not differentiate it like you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check wheather < select > is clicked by keyboard or mouse,
you can use mousedown() and keypress() event

```
$('select').mousedown(function(e){
  //your code on mouse select
});
```

and

```
$('select').keypress(function(e){
  //your code on key select
});
```